# Making MS Word show a dialog asking for document properties

Tags: microsoft-word

I have created a MS Word template depending on document properties. Is it possible to enable some sort of a flag in the document to make Word show the document properties dialog whenever a file is created using my template?

I don't prefer macros, as they would cause a warning dialog to appear. Is there a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not at document creation, but rather at the first save event, and is merely a setting, not a macro.

Word 97-2003 you can check Tools>Options>Save> Prompt for document properties, and the properties dialog will display before saving.

Comment: That setting is, I think, user specific, not document specific. If true, then all users must enable this option? I guess in that case all users could also be told to accept a macro.

Comment: @arjan, you might be able to use a [Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178949%28office.12%29.aspx) to make everyone's computer enable the prompt setting.

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be a different solution at the moment (excluding macros), I'm accepting this answer. Thanks.