# Make Document Properties Required for Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, metadata

There seems to be a solution for this problem, but only for Word 97-2003, per this post:

[Making MS Word show a dialog asking for document properties](https://superuser.com/questions/60850/making-ms-word-show-a-dialog-asking-for-document-properties)

I have it setup so that when a user opens a file the Document Properties pane is automatically displayed. I would like to take this a step further and make some of those properties required. Is there an easy way to do this?

It is frustrating because there is a **Required field** indicator next to the **Location** field in the Document Properties pane (so I know it can be done) but I do not know how to make other properties required. See screenshot.

[Required Document Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnJaQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK automatic prompting for document properties in 2013 and 2016 versions of Office are a function of a Document Library such SharePoint. Here are two references on the subject.

[How to Ensure that Users are Prompted for Document Metadata](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3045118/microsoft-subnet/how-to-ensure-that-users-are-prompted-for-document-metadata-in-office-365-and-sharepoint-2016.html)

[View or change the properties for an Office file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-or-change-the-properties-for-an-office-file-21d604c2-481e-4379-8e54-1dd4622c6b75#ID0EAABAAA=Office_2013_-_Office_2010)